# Logging solution for aws spot instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, elastic-stack

Is there any solution or way, which can help me to get live/real-time logs?

I have 100s of **Spot instances** that come and go frequently, So we need to configure a setup that captures the logs despite this spot life cycle, which means whenever new spot instance launches we will get the respective instance to log immediately.

please help/suggested the way.

Comment: The answer is to get the log entries off the instance as fast as they're written. But since you don't say _anything_ about how you're currently doing logging, any concrete answer is unlikely to apply to you.

Comment: I need any logging solution to collect my spot instances logs , as of now, I don't have any logging solution

Answer (score 0):

Use cloud watch agents to write logs to cloudwatch.